# How to make nested flatMap and map more comprehensible

Tags: swift, functional-programming, monads, for-comprehension

Suppose, we have a struct `M`:

```
public struct M<T> {
    let value: T
    public init(_ value: T) { self.value = value }

    public func map<U>(f: T -> U) -> M<U> { return M<U>(f(value)) }
    public func flatMap<U>(f: T -> M<U>) -> M<U> { return f(value) }
}
```

and a few functions which compute a value (`T`) and return it as a wrapped value with `M`:

```
func task1() -> M<Int> {
    return M(1)
}

func task2(value: Int = 2) -> M<Int> {
    return M(value)
}

func task3(value: Int = 3) -> M<Int> {
    return M(value)
}

func task4(arg1: Int, arg2: Int, arg3: Int) -> M<Int> {
    return M(arg1 + arg2 + arg2)
}
```

Now, suppose we want to compute the values of task1, task2 and task3 and then pass all three computed values as arguments to task4. It seems, this requires to use *nested calls* to `flatMap` and `map`:

```
let f1 = task1()
let f2 = task2()
let f3 = task3()

f1.flatMap { arg1 in
    return f2.flatMap { arg2 in
        return f3.flatMap { arg3 in
            return task4(arg1, arg2:arg2, arg3:arg3).map { value in
                print("Result: \(value)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't look quite comprehensible. Is there a way to improve that? For example, using custom operators?

Comment: If `task1`, `task2`, `task3` are not dependent on each other, then you can use `ap` variant from `Applicative Functor`. Then you'll get all the values at once. But yeah something like scala's for comprehension would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for reference, it would do well to document here what Haskell does in this situation:

```
example1 = do
  arg1 <- task1
  arg2 <- task2
  arg3 <- task3
  value <- task4 arg1 arg2 arg3
  putStrLn ("Result: " ++ show value)
```

This desugars to the `>>=` operator, which is a flipped infix flatMap:

```
-- (>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
-- 
-- It's a right-associative operator

example2 = task1 >>= \arg1 -> 
             task2 >>= \arg2 -> 
               task3 >>= \arg3 -> 
                 task4 arg1 arg2 arg3 >>= \value ->
                   putStrLn ("Result: " ++ show value)
```

So yeah, what you've done here is rediscover the motivation for Haskell's `do`-notation—it's precisely a special flat syntax for writing nested flatMaps!

But here's another trick that might be relevant to this example.  Note that in your computation, `task1`, `task2` and `task3` don't have any interdependencies.  This can be the basis for designing a "flat" utility construct for merging them into one task.  In Haskell, you can do this easily with the `Applicative` class and pattern matching:

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA3, (<$>), (<*>))

-- `liftA3` is the generic "three-argument map" function, 
-- from `Control.Applicative`.
example3 = do
  -- `liftA3 (,,)` is a task that puts the results of its subtasks
  -- into a triple.  We then flatMap over this task and pattern match
  -- on its result. 
  (arg1, arg2, arg3) <- liftA3 (,,) task1 task2 task3
  value <- task4 arg1 arg2 arg3
  putStrLn ("Result: " ++ show value)

-- Same thing, but with `<$>` and `<*>` instead of `liftA3`
example4 = do
  (arg1, arg2, arg3) <- (,,) <$> task1 <*> task2 <*> task3
  value <- task4 arg1 arg2 arg3
  putStrLn ("Result: " ++ show value)
```

If `task1`, `task2` and `task3` return the same type, then another way of flattening it is to use the `Traversable` class (which bottoms out to the same `Applicative` technique as above):

```
import Data.Traversable (sequenceA)

example5 = do
  -- In this use, sequenceA turns a list of tasks into a
  -- task that produces a list of the originals results.
  [arg1, arg2, arg3] <- sequenceA [task1, task2, task3]
  value <- task4 arg1 arg2 arg3
  putStrLn ("Result: " ++ show value)
```

So one idea then is to build an utility library that provides similar functionality.  Some example operations:

1. Combine heterogeneously typed tasks into a composite.  Signatures look like `(M<A1>, ..., M<An>) -> M<(A1, ..., An)>`
2. Multi-task map: map an *n*-place function over *n* tasks that produce the appropriate types.
3. Turn a sequence of tasks into a task that produces a sequence of their results.

Note that #1 and #2 have equivalent power.  And also note that if we're talking about asynchronous tasks, these operations have an advantage over flatmaps, which is that they're much easier to parallelize.